# Matrix with trace zero

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Question is that :

Suppose a matrix $A\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ is a commutator by which i mean $A=BC-CB$ for some $B,C\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ then we see that Trace of $A$ is $0$

But Suppose a matrix is of trace zero can we say that it is commutator?

I have tried seeing this for $2\times 2$ matrices and end up with nothing reasonable..

I would be thankful if some one can suggest me a way to proceed in this case.

Comment: Perhaps [this paper](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~wkahan/MathH110/trace0.pdf) would be of interest. The question that you are interested in appears to be the subject of Theorem 3.

Comment: @PeterWoolfitt : how did you get that? Thank you anyways :) :)

Comment: @copper.hat : Thank you :)

Comment: You are very welcome!